# How can I get parent categories in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a "Categories" table on my mysql database that has three columns: category_id, parent_category_id, category_name.
category_id is PK and Auto increment and parent_category_id holds a category's parent "categori_id". So I can relate categories in just one table.

For example:

```
category_id   parent_category_id   category_name
1             0                    USA
2             1                    California
3             2                    San Francisco
4             0                    Canada
5             4                    Alberta
6             5                    Calgary
```

I want to get a category and its all parents in a single query. This query should give me a result like:

```
USA > California > San Francisco
```

or

```
Canada > Alberta > Calgary
```

Opencart actually does something like this but it stores relationship data between categories in a different table. I want to do this in just one table and I've no idea what should I do.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of children to parent relationships?  If so, you can self `join` the table back to itself that many times.  If not, you'll need to use `dynamic sql`.

Comment: @sgeddes no, I don't.

Answer (score -1):

**This can be solved with only 1 simple query (SELECT * FROM categories), and a recursive function.**

Bear with me. Run PHP code myself, checked, confirmed result.

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/9741-0kms)

```
//To begin set a category_id, say our node is San Fransisco, so $category_id=3

//get San Fransisco's id
$node = 3

/* Get your database into array structure like this
$categories = array(
'1'=>array('parent'=>'0', 'name'=>'USA'),
'2'=>array('parent'=>'1', 'name'=>'California')
..
)
*/

$categories = array(); //or [] as of PHP 5.6
$qr = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories');
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qr))
{
    $categories[$row['category_id']] = array('parent'=>$row['parent_category_id'], 'name'=>$row['category_name']);
}


//first element of tree, is San Fransisco, category_id=3
$tree=array($node);

function getCategoryTree($node, & $tree){
  global $categories;
  if($categories[$node]['parent']==='0')
     return;

   $parent_id = $categories[$node]['parent'];
   $tree[]=$parent_id;

   return getCategoryTree($parent_id, $tree);

}

//do magick
getCategoryTree($node, $tree);

//now you have $tree=array(3,2,1);
$out='';
while($last = array_pop($tree))
{
   $out.= $categories[$last]['name'].' > ';
}

//outputs USA > California > San Francisco
echo $out;
```

Comment: Let's all keep our clothes on